# Spring Boot JPA+Hibernate low performance on SaveAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing a REST application to load CSV files, insert them into DB (MYSQL - mysqld  Ver 5.7.32), and then query and show the records in JSON format.

The problem is when I try to persist the records by using JPA repository SaveAll() method it takes a lot of time(~25s for 500 records).

I searched for the solutions and found some configuration changes that seems to solve the problem but none of them did for me.
I changed ***logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG*** and ***spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true*** to inspect how hibernate is working.

without any further changes to the application.properties results are as below for 500 records:

Id GenerationType.AUTO / ID: 14:13:30-14:13:52 / insert till: 14:13:53 / No Batch / No URL / 23s

```
17529760 nanoseconds spent acquiring 501 JDBC connections;
11900589 nanoseconds spent releasing 500 JDBC connections;
201149299 nanoseconds spent preparing 1500 JDBC statements;
946268444 nanoseconds spent executing 1500 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
511195616 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 500 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

22s for obtaining and updating the Id.

Hibernate executes 3 queries for every single entity that is passed to the SaveAll() method:

First it gets the needed IDs:

1. select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2. update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?

After getting the Id:

1. insert into table ...

As indicated by logs Hibernate executes 1500 statements for 500 records.

I tried changing the configuration as below:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
```

and got below results:

GenerationType.AUTO / ID: 14:23:30-14:23:52 / insert till:14:23:53  /  Batch size: 30, order_inserts=true / No URL / 23s

```
15672968 nanoseconds spent acquiring 501 JDBC connections;
13474276 nanoseconds spent releasing 500 JDBC connections;
116274083 nanoseconds spent preparing 1001 JDBC statements;
843429450 nanoseconds spent executing 1000 JDBC statements;
222390695 nanoseconds spent executing 17 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
346810255 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 500 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Statements are reduced to 1000 and 17 batches have been executed but still it takes 22s to get the IDs and 1s for executing the inserts.

I changed the Id generation strategy to SEQUENCE and the results were the same.
Also, I added ***?reWriteBatchedInserts=true*** to the MYSQL connection URL to insert multiple entities in one statement but still hibernate produces 1 insert per record:

```
2020-11-27 15:33:15.349 DEBUG 7061 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into enra (account_link_code_n, chanel_nam, contract_type_v, cra_ref_num_v, dms_verified_flag_v, id_type_v, msisdn_nsk, profile_type_v, registration_by, registration_date, report_date, shahkar_id, sim_category_code_v, status_code_v, user_code_n, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-11-27 15:33:15.349 DEBUG 7061 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into enra (account_link_code_n, chanel_nam, contract_type_v, cra_ref_num_v, dms_verified_flag_v, id_type_v, msisdn_nsk, profile_type_v, registration_by, registration_date, report_date, shahkar_id, sim_category_code_v, status_code_v, user_code_n, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-11-27 15:33:15.350 DEBUG 7061 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into enra (account_link_code_n, chanel_nam, contract_type_v, cra_ref_num_v, dms_verified_flag_v, id_type_v, msisdn_nsk, profile_type_v, registration_by, registration_date, report_date, shahkar_id, sim_category_code_v, status_code_v, user_code_n, version, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I have CSV files with ~40,000 records and this is creating a huge bottleneck in my application.

I really don't know what I'm missing in my configuration but it seems that if I can make the hibernate to obtain and update the Id (hibernate_sequence) in batches, time consumption would drop dramatically.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: From what I understood, there is no direct sequence support in MySQL. That's why there is the workaround with a table, which is not very performant. Not sure if this can be in batches by Hibernate, why not use MySQL auto_increment?

Comment: @Thomas I have tried with @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) but no changes.

Comment: I think it must be @Id @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false) @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) - check out bootify.io if you like.

Comment: @Thomas I used GenerationType.IDENTITY and surprisingly time of execution has improved dramatically although batching is disabled. Now it persists 40k records in about 28s. But as my CSV files could grow larger over time I think it might cause the first level cache to overflow.

Answer (score 2):

For the general audience - issue was the Generation Type. Because MySQL doesn't support sequence, hibernate used a workaround with a separate table. Before each row a read and a write was executed, thus performance went down.

Solution:

```
@Id
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

which uses the auto_increment feature, preferred option for MySQL. :-)